# Expressjs How to properly pass an array from the client and utilize it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an object that look like this:

```
editinvite: {
  _id: '',
  title: '',
  codes_list: []
}
```

The problem is that I can't access codes_list in my NodeJS app. It shows as 'undefined' (other non-array variables work fine though)

```
router.post('/inviteEdit', function (req, res) {
...
console.log(req.body.codes_list);

// Output:
undefined
```

**Note** that I'm trying to use `codes_list` as it is, I mean I want to pass it directly to my update parameters:

```
var update = {
        title: req.body.title,
        codes_list: req.body.codes_list,
    };
```

**(extra info)** Output of `console.log(req.body)`:

```
{ _id: '565981a16a75a7522afdcc8b',
  title: 'as',
  'codes_list[0][code]': '0EHC',
  'codes_list[0][_id]': '565981a16a75a7522afdcc8c',
  'codes_list[0][used]': 'false',
  'codes_list[1][code]': 'VDQ2',
  'codes_list[1][_id]': '565981a16a75a7522afdcc8d',
  'codes_list[1][used]': 'false' }
```

**(extra info)** `editinvite` object before sending, looks like this on FF debugger:
[image]

**(extra info)** My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: this.server + '/inviteEdit',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: this.editinvite,
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
   ...
```

**(extra info)** I'm using these parameters in node app

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: What about for `console.log(req.body.title);` for example, is it ok? Or is the problem with `code_list` only?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov oh yeah that works fine. it's the `codes_list` only

Comment: Can you share you express config where you have defined routes ?

Comment: @KunalKapadia Like what? I don't have any special config. Do you think it is related to routes ?

Comment: @xperator Can you set `extended` to `true` in bodyParser and try again ?

Comment: @KunalKapadia Oh wow thx! it's working now. Well honestly I don't know what does that option do... Could you please post an answer with a little explanation, So I could accept it and understand what was going on

Comment: @xperator Sure. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) documentation:

> `bodyParser.urlencoded(options)` returns middleware that only parses
>   urlencoded bodies. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
>
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the
>   request object after the middleware (i.e. `req.body`). This object will
>   contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array
>   (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).

So basically if you just want string or array to be parsed you can set extended to false, for other types (like in your case array of objects) you need to set it to true.